# How do I install nord theme in lazyvim?

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I'm new to vim (2 days in) and struggling to understand how to configure some things. How can I get nord theme installed and working? I added the plugin but the colorscheme doesn't show up. An example of catpuccin would also be good.

Comment: You can see the color schemes install by `ls –l /usr/share/vim/vim*/colors`.  Conversely if you want to install a new color scheme .. Just plop the downloaded `.vim` file in the `colors` directory.  The directory might not be the same, but it should be similar.  I am assuming that Neovim and any or ther vim derivative will be similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, have a look at this LazyVim documentation page: https://www.lazyvim.org/plugins/colorscheme which explains the general concept of changing themes.

Edit your `lua/plugins/colorscheme.lua` file (or create it if you don't already have one) in your nvim configuration directory.

For the "nord" theme you asked about, your `colorscheme.lua` file should look something like this:

```
return {
  { "shaunsingh/nord.nvim" },

  {
    "LazyVim/LazyVim",
    opts = {
      colorscheme = "nord",
    },
  },
}
```

For the "catpuccin" theme you asked about, the LazyVim documentation page linked above has a full example for configuring catpuccin!

Hope this helps...

Comment: Wanted to add my 2 cents: The name of the file doesn't matter. LazyVim will load all the files found in ~./config/nvim/plugins. What it is important (Thanks a bunch Mike) is to include the exact code Mike shown.  `{ "shaunsingh/nord.nvim" },` comes from GitHub and the ` { colorscheme = "nord" },` is how you specify the default theme